# Requesting a Cloud Shell.Failed to provision a Cloud Shell: {"code":"ServerTimeout","message":"The request timed out

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Suddenly from last few hours I'm getting timeout message from cloud shell. I have been stuck because of this. Could anyone pls. point out what could be the issue and how should I resolve it.

I'm working on some prototype and has free subscription available.

Comment: Do you try to restart the cloud shell?

Comment: I did. No success. I tried going incognito(read somewhere) but no success there to. Its just not opening

Comment: Try to open it with another browser? or do you use up your cost in a free Azure account? Azure offers eligible customers $200 in Azure credits (“Credits”) to be used within the first 30 days of sign-up. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/